# Round to the next integer - Robotframework

Tags: robotframework

Let's say I have a variable that stores a float number, e.g: **42.4**

How can I make Robot round up to the next Integer?

Example:

```
42.1 = 43
42.6 = 43
```

I always need to round up to the next integer, no matter how much is the decimal part. Is that possible?

I tried:

```
${var} = | Convert To Number | ${var} | 0
```

But when the decimal is less than 0.5, it rounds down.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out:

```
${var} | Evaluate | math.ceil(${var})
```